# EnvironmentMismatchError - Rails.env being set to "production"

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activerecord

I'm receiving a `Missing`secret_key_base`for 'production' environment, set this value in config/secrets.yml` error when checking localhost. This doesn't make sense, since I should be in development.

I logged `Rails.env` during the server start, and it is showing `development`.

From there I tried some database stuff:

- `rails dbconsole` gets me this error: `psql: FATAL:  role "my-server" does not exist`
- `rails db:create` gets me this:

> `Database 'my-server_development' already exists`
>
> `Database 'my-server_test' already exists`

- Next I decided to try `rails db:create`, which gave me the most indicative error:

> ActiveRecord::EnvironmentMismatchError: You are attempting to modify a database that was last run in `development` environment.
>   You are running in `production` environment. If you are sure you want to continue, first set the environment using:
>
> > bin/rails db:environment:set RAILS_ENV=production

In conclusion, some mystery config in my environment seems to be set to production. This error is suggesting that I try to set my rails env to production to match it, but what I want is to change that mystery something to development.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check in your terminal if `RAILS_ENV` is set with `env | grep RAILS_ENV`. In case yes run `unset RAILS_ENV`.

Comment: @DennyMueller it doesn't appear to be set in ENV, `env | grep RAILS_ENV` returns nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay figured it out. I had a typo in one of my initializers and was checking my Rails env like so:

```
if Rails.env = "production"
  # blahblah do something
```

This of course was setting `Rails.env` to `"production"`. I messing around with Pry in the Rails startup process, and I figured out that `Rails.env` was returning `"development"` at one point, and `"production"` later on.

From there, a quick search found the problem. Thanks to everyone who took the time to look at this. I'll update the title to something more indicative of the problem.